# Load a file while C++ program is running

Tags: c++, xml, file, sockets

I have a C++ program which reads data from a socket and loads it into an xml file. I have another function in the same program that is called after the data is loaded which parses the xml file. The problem here is the data actually appears in the file only after the program is closed. Hence the xml parser is unable to read data. Is there a way to load the file as soon as data is read?

Comment: Did you close the file handle after writing to file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to close the file handle after writing to it and before reading it.
Alternatively, you can open the file in read/write mode.